# Angular update model data maintain selected option in select list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and trying to work with a Product object. The Product object contains many Sku objects within it.

A user can use my app to fetch a product, which returns the Product object, containing Sku objects within it. When the Product object is returned, it's set equal to the `$scope.product` variable like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.product;

    //this will contain the selected sku model that's selected in the dropdown
    $scope.selectedSku;

    /*
    * Get a product and all of it's data from the server
    */
    $scope.getProduct = function(){
            $http.post('get_product', {product_id: $scope.extProductId}).
            success(function(product){
                    $scope.product = product;
            }).
            error(function(data){
                    console.log('something went wrong');
            });
    };
```

As you can see, there is an additional variable called `$scope.selectedSku`. This variable holds the Sku object currently selected in the select list.  The select list looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="selectedSku" ng-options="sku.sku for sku in product.skus">
    <option value=""> -- Select SKU -- </option>
</select>
```

There are certain points during the users interaction with the app, that I want to re-fetch the Product object from the server. When I do this, I again set the result to `$scope.product`, just as before.  However, when I do this, the select list is no longer has the correct option selected.  Instead it goes back to showing the `"-- Select SKU --" option.

I'm assuming this is because the underlying data is being replaced with a new Product object.  Is there any way for Angular to maintain this connection to the selectedSku when the Product object is re-fetched?

Or, is the solution to keep track of the ID of the selected SKU, and then programmatically reselect that SKU after the Product is re-fetched?

The Product object, which contains the Sku objects, looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Product Name",
    skus: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Sku 1 Name",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Sku 2 Name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is the data structure of `sku` object?

Comment: I just added this to the end of the question. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to sacrifice the whole object in the model, you can do something like this and use ng-repeat instead of ng-options.

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="selectedSku" >
        <option value=""> -- Select SKU -- </option>
        <option ng-repeat="sku in product.skus" ng-selected="{{ sku.id == selectedSku }}" ng-value="sku.id" ng-bind="sku.id"></option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="resetProductSkus()">Reset Product Skus</button>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.product = {
        skus: [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]
    };

    $scope.resetProductSkus = function() {
        console.log('resetting products');
        $scope.product = angular.copy($scope.product);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nobsex5t/26/

Comment: Thank you this is a great suggestion. However, I want to display information on the page based on some of the other properties of the selected SKU. Can this be done if the model only contains the ID? Would I need to use `ng-change` on the select to update the SKU information displayed on the page?

Comment: You could certainly use ng-change and then store the object. For a slightly more hack-y approach, instead of embedding the ng-selected code in the attribute, use a function, and when it finds equality store the object somewhere else. Let me know if that doesn't make sense to you - I can update the fiddle.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind updating the fiddle to demonstrate, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

var selectedProduct =  find product from $scope.product.skus based on product's id etc. and then do:
$scope.product = selectedProduct ;